# Elasticsearch add node to cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 node elasticsearch cluster

```
192.168.2.11 - node-01
192.168.2.12 - node-02
192.168.2.13 - node-03
```

and i deleted node-02 from cluster using this command

```
curl -XPUT 192.168.2.12:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "transient" :{
      "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "192.168.2.12"
   }
}'
```

and ok, all my indexes moved to node-01 and node-03, but how to return back this node to the cluster?
i try this command

```
curl -XPUT 192.168.2.12:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "transient" :{
      "cluster.routing.allocation.include._ip" : "192.168.2.12"
   }
}'
```

but this doesn't works
`:"node does not cluster setting [cluster.routing.allocation.include] filters [_ip:\"192.168.2.12\"]`

Answer (score 0):

The node has not been deleted but you can 'undo' your command by updating the setting you changed to `null`

Try updating the settings on either of the running nodes (01 or 03) with

```
"transient" :{
  "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : null
}
```

and the cluster should rebalance shards across the three nodes.
Be careful using the `include._ip: "192.168.2.12"` as this might stop routing indices to the other two, instead include all three ip addresses if you wanted to us this, for example

```
"transient" :{
  "cluster.routing.allocation.include._ip" :"192.168.2.11, 192.168.2.12, 192.168.2.13"
}
```